# List globally installed npm modules programatically

Tags: node.js, npm

How do I get a list of all globally installed npm packages using the `npm.commands.ls` command?

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to have npm installed locally(`npm i npm -S`). Second, you need to do `npm.load` to initialize npm. Finally you can just use `npm.commands.ls` to get the list. What is important is to add the `global: true` and `depth: 0` parameters into the load function.

```
var npm = require('npm')

npm.load({
    loaded: false,
    progress: false,
    loglevel: 'error',
    global: true,
    depth: 0
}, () => {
    npm.commands.ls([], true, (err, data) => {
        console.log(Object.keys(data.dependencies))
    })
})
```